# How to get the value from this yaml?

Tags: java, yaml

The map is filled with this key: ms-outlook. There is no "application/vnd." in front of it, and i need the whole line as a key. Is there something wrong in yaml format, or java code?

This is the yaml file:

```yaml
allowedUploadFileTypes:
  application/vnd.ms-outlook:
    - application/octet-stream
```

This is java code:

```java
private Map<String, List<String>> allowedUploadFileTypes = new HashMap<>();
@MapValue(value = "allowedUploadFileTypes")
public Map<String, List<String>> getAllowedUploadFileTypes() {
    return allowedUploadFileTypes;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, we don't see how you're loading the YAML file, you don't even tell us which library you use to do so.

Comment: That and your choice of key makes references via delimiters pretty hard: `my.example.key` => `allowedUploadFileTypes.application/vnd.ms-outlook...`, you'd have to go the classic route of getting each object, then the child object, etc

Comment: @Rogue YAML does not define any kind of delimiters and since keys do not need to be scalars (`[1, 2]` could be a key) that wouldn't work anyway in the general case. It is perfectly valid and to problem at all to use `.` within a YAML key. You seem to be thinking of a very specific API that provides access via some kind of joined path.

Comment: @flyx It's common across a few apis, but in general while it's perfectly valid, I would argue it isn't ideal to store keys with common escapes/delimiters (`.`, `\``, `/`, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the replays.The java code is not needed to be shown in this case, cause there is no regex or splitting at all at java side, anything that will be skipping that special characters ( . / ) . So after digging a lot with YAML, i found that the dot ( . ) and everything before the dot is NOT considered as a value for the key(but YAML don't throw error). Just to mention, it is a value that TIKA will find and need in order my code to work properly ( it is for .pst files (Outlook)). So, i  re-write in YAML like:  application/vnd-dot-ms-outlook and replacing -dot- with . in java side. @Rogue

Comment: @MartinBozinovski As far as YAML is concerned, the dot and everything before it is definitely part of the key. It is whatever you use to load the YAML file that treats dots in a special way. Loading the YAML file with SnakeYAML would give you the whole key including the dot etc.